# How to search for a specific string in couchbase array

Tags: json, nosql, couchbase, sql++

I have JSON documents of below format:

```
{
  "id":"1005",
  "config":{
      "properties":["ABC_001", "DEF_002", "PQR_009"]
   }
}
```

How can I search for a particular config.properties that matches pattern '%ABC%' and has an id=1005. In the above case, my output should be

```
config.properties:ABC_001
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This gets you close:

```
select prop as `config.properties` 
from test unnest config.properties prop
where test.id = "1005" and prop like '%ABC%'
```

Here's the output:

```
[
  {
    "config.properties": "ABC_001"
  }
]
```